# TSQL/MySQL Equivalents

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I've spent a lot of time in SQL Server product, but not so much in mySQL. I'm aware of the most basic differences in their SQL implementation, i.e. `TOP 1" == "LIMIT 1"` and so forth, but once we enter the world of programmability, I am absolutely clueless as to what built-in functions mySQL does and does not have.

I can find documentation on the mySQL functions by themselves easily enough, but I'm wondering if there's a document of some kind that simply lists SQL Server functions and their mySQL equivalents (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may help:

[Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/)

Functions in particular are here: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#functions